# Observer viewcontroller lifecycle using KVO, not work

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, lifecycle, key-value-observing

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"title" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isBeingPresented" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context  {
    NSLog(@"%@", keyPath);
}
```

I have one navigationcontroller, I want to know if one viewcontroller is disappear or appear, except using normal lifecycle events. Anyone can help ? 
 Thanks

Comment: In which file you are writing this Observer code?

Comment: I write code in viewcontrol.m itself, i may write code in a singleton object later. So user input his viewcontroller in the method that the singleton object provides.

Comment: I have used the same code and it is working fine.